# How do you Configure the Connection String for ODP.NET Connection String with FailOver?

Tags: oracle, connection-string, odp.net

Converting to ODB.NET from System.Data.OracleClient and need help converting my connection string.  Here is what I use with System.Data.OracleClient.

> SERVER=(DESCRIPTION_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=yes)(FAILOVER=ON)(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.26.140.80)(PORT=9960))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.26.140.81)(PORT=9960)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=tactota))));uid=XXXXXXX;pwd=XXXXXXXX"

Here is what I have gotten to work with ODB.NET, but does not implement the other features of the above connection string.

> Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.26.140.80)(PORT=9960)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=tactota)));User Id=XXXXXXXX;Password=XXXXXXXX;

Here is what I got when I tried to roll them together, but needless to say it did not work.

> Data Source=(LOAD_BALANCE=yes)(FAILOVER=ON)(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.26.140.80)(PORT=9960))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.26.140.81)(PORT=9960)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=tactota))); User Id=XXXXXX;Password=XXXXX;

Thanks!

Dave

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally got it to work!  Here is what I came up with

> Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=yes)(FAILOVER=ON)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.26.140.80)(PORT=9960))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.26.140.81)(PORT=9960)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=tactota))); User Id=XXXXXXX;Password=XXXXXXXX;

Comment: Did you need to make any changes to your C# code to handle the failover?