# ODP.NET and C# question

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oracle

I'm trying to connect Oracle database using ODP.NET but it's not working. I've installed ODP.net ( guess 11g ) for .NET and trying to connect 10g express edition which is installed on my local machine.

I've included following library in my code,

```
using System.Data;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
```

Still I'm getting "oracleconnection is a namespace but used like a type" error.

[image]

Any idea?

update :
[image]

Update:

By changing namespace as suggested below and modifying connecting string, it works. My connection string now,

```
string constr = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=host)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));
User Id=system; Password=password";
```

Comment: Look at your code and at namespace name. Please change name of namespace you have used in your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not import **using [System.Data.OracleClient](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B28089_01/OracleConnectionClass.htm);**

**Edit:**

Change the name of namespace you have used in your program.

Comment: thanks, I've updated as you said and edited this post.. See above. still the same problem.

Comment: Look at your code and at namespace name. Please change name of namespace you have used in your application/program.

Comment: Thanks for pointing something silly..Still not able to connect. It says not connected , no errors. Any thoughts ?

Comment: @Rishi, have a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540529/how-do-you-configure-the-connection-string-for-odp-net-connection-string-with-fai

Comment: Something is not right in connection, it's taking hell of a time to connect my local Oracle client. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use one data provider, conflict occurs because of using System.Data.OracleClient;
If you are confused which data provider should use then view the [difference](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=2226074).

Comment: Thanks! Actually I need to build a SharePoint web part which will connect to Oracle database and display records on SP page.I've chosen ODP.NET because it does't require Oracle client to be installed. Hope I read it right.For start, I'm trying to connect local oracle db using C# but eventually I require something which don;t need Oracle client.